# Why Rectangle Fill isnt changing?

Tags: c#, wpf

Here is my code. Visibillity changes successfully but Fill doesnt...( I know that I wont see the difference because I set it to collapsed but without visibility setter color doesnt change)

```
<Rectangle Fill="#FFC8B65E" Stroke="#FF353434" RadiusX="5" RadiusY="7" StrokeThickness="2">
    <Rectangle.Style>
        <Style>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger  Binding="{Binding TableOrder}" Value="{x:Null}">
                    <Setter Property="Shape.Fill" Value="White" />
                    <Setter Property="Rectangle.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Rectangle.Style>
</Rectangle>
```

It seems that `<Rectangle Fill="#FFC8B65E"` is more important..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the answer here: [WPF Style: how to change GradientStop Color in Trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487814/wpf-style-how-to-change-gradientstop-color-in-trigger)
It should help you solve your problem (use resources).

Answer (score 1):

try removing `Fill="#FFC8B65E"`

because of [Dependency Property Value Precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx#Dependency%20Properties%20Might%20Be%20%22Set%22%20in%20Multiple%20Places) even you set style property it will be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

The string `White` isn't a valid colour.

Comment: It's still not a valid colour. Create a colour resource and use that.

Comment: WPF interprets it as a `string`, not a `Color` object, which is why you're having problems.